# EditPad: Find and Replace with RegEx Backreferences

Tags: regex, replace, backreference, editpad

I'm trying my hand at regex again. In particular, using a backreference to found text in the replace string in the EditPad text editor.

**Subject:**

> Product1 Desc,12 PIN,GradeA Qty Price
>   Product2 Desc,28 PIN,GradeA Qty Price

**Goal:**
Since the text is currently space-separated, I need to replace `12 PIN` with `12||PIN`, and `28 PIN` with `28||PIN`.

**What I'm trying:**
`[(0-9)]+[(\s)]PIN` seems to be finding what I want just fine.
When I try to replace with backrefereces, though, the only one I can get to work is `\0`.
For example, using `\0||PIN` as my replace gives me `12 PIN||PIN`.
When I try to replace with `\1||PIN`, however, it gives `||PIN`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have sworn that I saw a previous poster answer this...

Using this as your find string:

```
([0-9]+)[\s]*PIN
```

and this as your replace string:

```
\1||PIN
```

should do it.